How are oslexec.lib and oslexec_d.lib compiled?
I'm currently trying to change a method in the oslexec library so I can add extra math for closure types (it's a long story). So I was needing to compile oslexec.lib and possibly oslexec_d.lib, from the Open Shading Language (OSL) repository. I was wondering if anyone knew if Blender uses the standard oslexec library or if there were additional changes added to it for use in Blender? The reason is when I do compile the oslexec library folder (in the osl repo specifically), and then paste it into blender's repo before compiling, I get link errors 2019/2001 relating to OpenImageIO. I didn't know if the reason for this was because additional code is added to oslexec when it is compiled into oslexec.lib?
Or the other possibility which is also likely, I originally was trying to compile all of osl, however I got stuck adding/installing the various dependencies for it through CMAKE. So after persistent trial and error I ended up realizing I could compile oslexec individually and it at least built fine. Though now I'm thinking by not making all of osl with the dependencies it needs, that's why the oslexec.lib file displays link errors when compiling blender.
So in summary: Is the oslexec library code changed at all from it's OSL source code for blender? Also does all of OSL need to be compiled with it's dependencies for oslexec library folder to build correctly into oslexec.lib?
Thanks,
Nate

for questions about the source code of Blender and such, you'd probably get more answers by asking on the official Blender chat with the devs. See Community — blender.org
